# Problems getting Canvas to render base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, base64

I'm not a javascript expert (am a JAVA/ATG developer), and am having some trouble with the below:

I'm trying to get the value of a previously encoded base64 image to render on a canvas.

The value for the base 64 image is coming from a Java Bean.

My code is as follows:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src =  dataURIStringSyntax.value + imgData.value;
imageObj.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
}
```

... where `dataURIStringSyntax` is the 'data:image/jpg;base64," part of the image, and `imgData` is the base64 code. These are set using `var dataURIStringSyntax = document.getElementById("dataURIStringSyntaxString");` and `var imgData = document.getElementById("dataURL");`

This results in a black block being rendered on the canvas, not the actual image.

But, if I do the following:

```
imageObj.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RD0...
```

the image is rendered on the canvas as I'd expect.

What can I be doing wrong? Could the way I'm buidling `imgObj.src` above by adding the relevant values to it be corrupting something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: It turned out the original encoding of the image was corrupt, so having fixed that, it's now working.
Thanks for those that made suggestions. :)

Comment: you are missing a comma in the concatenation, aren't you?

Comment: Having checked, no. The `dataURISyntaxString` is 'data:image/jpg;base64,'. Should there be another one?

Comment: Try to log the constructed string to console (`console.log(dataURIStringSyntax.value + imgData.value)` and copy/paste that into a new tab/address bar. If it is correct the image should show.

Comment: Good call... and it shows a black block, as I'm getting on the page. So the values in the concatinated string are at fault. Time to dig deeper. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the onload function above the .src. The image may have already been loaded when generated, and so the onload is called before it's set.